# jquery cookie uses the previous value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, wijmo

This is the generated code of my accordion:

```
<div id="treeview-accordion">
<h3><a href="#" accindex="0">Basic</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul class="navigation-treeview treeview-sanjo" id="yw0">
        <li><span style="font-weight:bold"><a href="/sanjo/site/index"> Home</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><span> Profile</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile"> View Profile</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/edit"> Update Profile</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/changepassword"> Change Password</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span> Personnel Management</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/admin"> Manage Personnel</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user"> List Personnel</a></span></li>
                    <li><span> Add Personnel</a></span></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="#" accindex="1">Basic2</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul class="navigation-treeview treeview-sanjo" id="yw01">
        <li><span style="font-weight:bold"><a href="/sanjo/site/index2"> Home2</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><span> Profile</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile2"> View Profile2</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/edit2"> Update Profile2</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/changepassword2"> Change Password2</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span> Personnel Management2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/admin2"> Manage Personnel2</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user2"> List Personnel2</a></span></li>
                    <li><span> Add Personnel2</a></span></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And everytime I click on a link, I am saving a value in the cookie "sanjotreeaccordion" based on which `<h3>` the link is under:

```
$("#tree-accordion a").bind("click",function(){
                    var cookie=$(this).closest("div").prev("h3").find("a").attr("accindex");
                    $.cookie("sanjotreeaccordion", cookie); 
                    alert($.cookie("sanjotreeaccordion"));
                   });
```

Then on page reload, I get the cookie "sanjotreeaccordion" value, so I can use it to determine which accordion pane to open:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($.cookie('sanjotreeaccordion'));
    var ind = ($.cookie('sanjotreeaccordion') || 0)*1;
    $('#tree-accordion').wijaccordion({'autoHeight':false,'requireOpenedPane':false,'selectedIndex':ind});
    $.cookie('sanjotreeaccordion',ind);    
});
```

You might have noticed that I have there alerts, and I use it to determine the value of the cookie. WijAccordion is the function creating the accordion, and will open the pane depending on the value of its `selectedIndex` option (`0` means first pane,`1` means 2nd,and so on).

Now the wierd part (I am doing the next part as I type).

Initially, when I ran my codes, the cookie does not exist yet so it will open the first pane (cookie is null,so it returns `0` then multiplied to `1`). And then that value will be saved to the cookie. (I checked the cookie,it is `0`).

Then I clicked on a link on the second pane, so I expect it to save `1` in the cookie (the alert said that the value of the cookie is `1`). But when the page reloaded, the alert of the cookie value is still `0`. When I clicked on any link again, that will be time when the cookie value is changed to `1`. In other words,I am getting the supposedly previous value of the cookie when page reloads.

Where is the problem with my codes?or is it my logic that is incorrect? Am I not following the sequence that I want to follow, which is

1. click a link
2. get "accindex" of its upper `<h3>`
3. save the value to the cookie
4. page reloads
5. get the value of the cookie
6. use the cookie value to open the appropriate pane of the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things for you to look at:

1) I don't know if this is just a typo in your question or not, but your container div  actually has the id "treeview-accordion" and yet, you're binding the click event to anchors within an element which has the id "tree-accordian". So this could explain why the cookie is not being set correctly at this point.

2) You're also setting a cookie after you initialise the accordian on each page using the index that's been set. So this 'could' be the reason why you are seeing the strange behaviour.

That would be where I would start looking for the solution. I don't have access to an environment where I can check it out fully with the plugins you're using right now, but if this doesn't guide you in the right direction, will be happy to look at in more detail.

Comment: Hi pollo,thanks for the reply. I tried finding "tree-accordian", and it is not found in the codes I pasted.Probably you're in a hurry while reading it :p

The codes here were copied-pasted as is, and it is alerting with my clicks so I guess that's a proof that the IDs were called properly.

Comment: Hi Macinville, sorry my typo - it was tree-accordion (notice the "on" at the end not "an" as in my previous comment. Hope that helps...